# google map click on markers

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-markers

I have a map and multiple markers on that. I have already attached a `click` event on the map container to disappearing whatever is shown over the map (I have legends, timeline, etc.) using animation.

My problem is when you click on a marker to see the `infoWindow`, it also triggers the `click` event on the map, which disappearing over layer objects on the map. So, I want to prevent the map container already assigned event, when clicking on a marker, so only infoWindow would appears and nothing else.

Here is map click event:

```
$('#map_canvas').bind('mousedown', function() { ...
```

The only thing I can see on the markers, is that they all have the same class: `gmnoprint`

I've already tested this one:

```
$('#map_canvas').not('.gmnoprint').bind('mousedown', function() { ...
```

and:

```
$('#map_canvas').bind('mousedown', function() {

    if ($(this).is('.gmnoprint'))
        return false;
....
```

But none of them worked. Anyone knows how to solve the problem?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is

```
$('#map_canvas').bind(...
```

those markers/info windows are in that map_canvas div, so your technically clicking on it

Comment: yeah, that's totally true! I knew that :(

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to use the google maps API event listeners, as they will be the most reliable when interacting with elements of the map:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/overlays#InfoWindows

This is the basic syntax from the gmaps API for binding a click to open an info window associated with a marker:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.open(map,marker);
});
```

Hopefully that will help!

Comment: thanks, I'm using the same. But what about preventing the map click event to not triggered when clicking on a marker?

Answer (score 1):

You have to catch the `event` and then call `event.preventDefault` where you have the `.click` function for the infoWindow.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like that

```
    <div id="map_canvas" class="foo"></div>


$("#map_canvas").hasClass("foo").click(function(){

 $(this).removeClass("foo")
})
```

Comment: it seems tricky, could you explain more how it could solve the problem? thanks. :)

Comment: @Mahdi just add a class `foo` to the div and make a click event on that class and then remove the class .If the class will not present than no further click event will be called.So `infoWindow` will remains visible and no click event will be called on map.Atlast again add the class to `map` to activate the click handler

Comment: I understand that now much better, but not sure if I could implement that or not. I have other things happening there and it's not simple as I explained above. However, thanks and seems a working solution. I'm gonna test that now ... :)